# Bulk update SQL Server C#

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a 270k-row database with primary key `mid` and a column called `value`, and I have a text file with mid's and values. Now I would like to update the table such that each value is assigned to the correct mid.

My current approach is reading the text file from C#, and updating a row in the table for each line that I read. There must be quicker way to do things I feel.. any ideas?

EDIT: There are other columns in the table, so I really need a method to *update* according to mid.

Comment: SqlBulkCopy into a temporary table or you could try UPDATE with a TVP.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use the SQL Server Import and Export Wizard:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141209.aspx

Alternatively you could use the `BULK` TSQL Statement:

```
BULK
INSERT YourTable
FROM 'c:\YourTextFile.txt'
WITH
(
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
GO


SELECT * FROM YourTable
GO
```

Assuming you are splitting on a comma delimiter.  If you are using another character such as a space, change the FIELDTERMINATOR to the associated character.

Edit (To achieve the update from my comment):

```
UPDATE RealTable
SET value = tt.value
FROM
  RealTable r
INNER JOIN temp_table tt ON r.mid = tt.mid
```

Comment: Thanks. If i'm correct this will not update but insert into the table, right? I edited my question with extra info, my apologies. What about using your method to create a new table and then join them on mid?

Comment: @Freek8 - ah I see.  Yes this would insert from a text file.  You could store these results in a temporary table (Using the BULK query provided) and then use an UPDATE statement based upon the temp table

Comment: @Freek8 - I have now included the SQL needed to achieve this in my answer.  You will have to adjust the table names accordingly.

Comment: I think this is still taking a very long time, perhaps just as long as my original idea `(read a line, update a row)`

Comment: @Freek8 - okay.  You are updating a lot of data here, so it will take some time.  You could try and apply an index on the column "value" which may help with query performance.

Comment: @Freek8 - did you made shure that the index fragmentation of the primary key is low?

Comment: @DarrenDavies I always thought that building indexes made `UPDATE` slower because of index rebuilding (http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql-index.htm). @Jahu no idea how to check this :/

Comment: @Freek8 - depends on if the index is CLUSTERED or NON CLUSTERED.  In this context you would be using a NON CLUSTERED index.  Would be entirely how SQL Server interprets the query and writes the execution plan.  You could apply it and include the actual execution plan and decide if it speeds it up/slows it down via this.

Comment: @DarrenDavies so I know how to build an index on the value-column via Server Management Studio, is there anything else I need to do after that? Or will MSSQL automatically use it to speed up queries?

Comment: @Freek8 - apply the index, include the execution plan and run the query.  SQL Server will take care of the rest.

Comment: @DarrenDavies include execution plan?

Comment: @Freek8 - you can include the execution plan by pressing CTRL M in SQL Server Management Studio

Answer (score 1):

Do you reuse the `SqlCommand`?

```
    struct Item
    {
        public int mid;
        public int value;
    }

    public int Update(string connectionstring)
    {
        int res = 0;
        using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand())
        using (cmd.Connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(connectionstring))
        {
            cmd.CommandText = @"UPDATE [table] SET [value] = @value WHERE [mid] = @mid;";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter mid = cmd.Parameters.Add("@mid", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter value = cmd.Parameters.Add("@value", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            try
            {
                cmd.Connection.Open();
                foreach (Item item in GetItems("pathttothefile"))
                {
                    mid.Value = item.mid;
                    value.Value = item.value;
                    res += cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                cmd.Connection.Close();
            }
        }
        return res;
    }

    IEnumerable<Item> GetItems(string path)
    {
        string[] line;
        foreach (var item in System.IO.File.ReadLines(path))
        {
            line = item.Split(',');
            yield return new Item() { mid = int.Parse(line[0]), value = int.Parse(line[1]) };
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes i'm reusing the `sqlcommand` but it is still taking very long